# Is there any closed form for the finite sum $1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots+\frac1n?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, self-learning, harmonic-numbers

I know that the infinite summation 
$$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}+...$$
is divergent and also the sequence
$$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}-\ln n$$
is convergent.

I wonder that whether there exist a formula (closed form) for the obtain value of the following finite summation.
$$1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}$$
If not why?

Comment: It's not at all clear how this series is defined, unless the fourth term should be $\frac{1}{4}$, in which case no such closed form is known.

Comment: in addition to @J.J. comment: check out the Harmonic series

Comment: @J.J. Thanks. I know that $\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k}> \ln (n+1)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \dfrac{1}{k}> 1+ \dfrac{n}{2}.$ I wont to know that why there does not exist a such closed form. Have any one prove that there can not be a such closed form?

Comment: @Nilan I think you are looking for the $n^{th}$ harmonic number, $H_n$ but in the future, it would be better for you to explicitly state your series.

Comment: @Nilan the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1/k-ln(k))$ is divergent, too-not convergent.

Comment: @calculus Search for Euler Mascheroni_constant

Comment: @Nilan Now it is clear, what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$H_n~=~\psi(n+1)+\gamma~=~-\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-\sqrt[n]x\Big)~dx~=~\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x~~}~dx,$$ where $\psi$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant). See [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) for more details.

Comment: OP $\displaystyle 1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=H_n$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}=H_n$$

where $H_n$ is the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.